# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container --- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I have been having a problem with the following:

```
package keyz;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyPractise extends JFrame{
    public static int x;
    public static int z;
    public static float hue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Color Square");
        KeyPractise content = new KeyPractise((window.getWidth() / 2), window.getHeight() / 2);
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setLocation(400,400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setVisible(true);
        content.requestFocusInWindow();
        content.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public KeyPractise (int xx, int zz){
        xx = x;
        zz = z;

        Listener listener = new Listener();
        addKeyListener(listener);

    }

    private class Listener implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int key = evt.getKeyCode();

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                if ((hue + 0.00392) < 1.00000){
                hue += 0.00392;
                }
                if ((hue + 0.00392) >= 1.00000){
                    hue -= hue;
                }
                repaint();
            }


        }//keyPressed

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1.0F, 1.0F));

            g.fillRect(x, z, 50, 50);

        }
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

I believe the problem is that I am "adding a window to a container."
If so, what other way can this be done to avoid the scenario?

Also, I was told it is proper style to add the `setBackground(Color);` method to the `KeyPractise` Object constructor and then add `super.paintComponent(g);` to `paintComponent()` rather than what I did. But when I do so I get this error in Eclipse:

> The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type Object

Is it bad to use `content.setBackground()` in the main subroutine?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you pleas mention the line - at which your are getting the errors?

Comment: @Razib: `window.setContentPane(content);` most likely

Comment: Line 20 is where it is at

Comment: Thank you for posting that link, but how would you go about using a Jpanel instead? I don't know much about JPanels yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed below line

```
public class KeyPractise extends JFrame{
```

to

```
public class KeyPractise extends Container{
```

and it is working now...
Please check

Comment: Yeah, I don't get that error anymore, but the program (the idea of the program is to draw a square on the screen that changes color as the user presses the up arrow key) doesn't exactly work. Could this be because of the change? ... On second thought I probably just did something wrong in the paintComponent method. I'll double check it. Thanks.